# UBUNTU C++ compiler not finding header files

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to compile a basic c++ program with 3 files: *main.cpp*, *file.h*, and *file.cpp*.

When I put
 `c++ -pthread *.cpp`  it give me an error saying;

```
fatal error: file.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

*main.cpp* and *file.cpp* both have `#include "file.h"`

Comment: Is `file.h` in the same directory?

Comment: I suppose you run `g++ -pthread *.cpp`not `c++ -pthread *.cpp`?

Comment: @Haatschii, they're the same on my ubuntu machine.  What are you getting at?

Comment: try add -I<path where file.h can be found> and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, file.h is in the same directory as the other files and only main.cpp and file.cpp are in that directory @Haatschii I've tried both already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g++ -I. *.cpp
```

This tell the compiler to find the header files on the current directory, and not only in the default directories (/usr/include and /include).

I suggest you for compiling this trivial example to use GNU Make. The standard rules will work for you.

```
make file.cpp main.cpp
```

Maybe, if you have the same issue (file.h not found) you can set CXXFLAGS=-I.

Comment: Thanks, this ended up working (even though my code didn't ;). I've tried the -I option before to no avail because of that pesky little "." after the -I option.

Comment: The -I option can be used several times, if you have your include files in several locations.